# Не работает скрипт на C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

движок Unity выдает вот такую ошибку

> ((46,16): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods)

и вот такую

> ((63,11): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods), как её решить

```
public float speed;

public float jumpForce;

 private float moveInput;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    private bool facingRight = true;

    private bool isGrounded;

    public Transform groundCheck;

    public float checkRadius;

    public LayerMask whatIsGround;

    private int extraJumps;

    public int extraJumpsValue;

    private void Start()
    {
        extraJumps = extraJumpsValue;

        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }


    private void FixedUpdate()

    {

        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);

        moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);


        if (facingRight == false && moveInput > 0)

        {

            Flip();

        }

        else if (facingRight == true && moveInput < 0)

        {

            Flip();

        }

    }

} 


  private void Update()

{

    if (isGrounded == true)

    {

        extraJumps = extraJumpsValue; 

    }


    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && extraJumps > 0)

    {

        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;

        extraJumps--; 

    }

    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && extraJumps == 0 && isGrounded == true)
    {

        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce; 

    }

} 

     void Flip()

{

    facingRight = !facingRight;

    Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;

    Scaler.x *= -1;

    transform.localScale = Scaler; 

}
```

Comment: для начаоа оформите код, чтобы его можно было читать. К тому же, у вас проблема с `namespace`, которого нет в коде, что вы показали.

Comment: Такая ошибка говорит о том, что вы пытаетесь писать функции и поля не в классе, а внутри самого namespace за пределами класса. Ну и да, самое важное вы как раз и не включили в вопрос - это класс и namespace, которые там должны быть (если они вообще есть).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В начале добавьте строчку

```
Public class "тут введите имя скрипта" : MonoBehever{
```

В конце необходимо добавить — `}`